# Not able to access Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Kubernetes question: I seem to not be able to access my service from my local machine (pods are running on minikube), when I run the command
kubectl `describe pod pod-id` I see these two lines but I don't know if they have anything to do with not being able to access the deployment:

```
Port:           8888/TCP
Host Port:      0/TCP
```

But when I run

```
kubectl get services
```

I see no External-IP

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
ci-master    NodePort    10.103.13.96   <none>        8888:31388/TCP   1m
```

Here's my `service.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ci-master
  labels:
    app: ci
    tier: fullstack
    role: master
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    targetPort: 8888
  selector:
    app: ci
    role: master
    tier: fullstack
```

And the part that I think should be relevant in my `deployment.yaml`:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ci
        image: rand/image-one:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
```

When I try to access the service with `minikube service ci-master` I get this message indefinitely:
`Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...`

The service is serving, when I try `kubectl describe pod pod-id` I see this line at the bottom:

```
  Type    Reason                 Age   From               Message
  Normal  Started                24m   kubelet, minikube  Started container
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I was missing was the Service Type, if I want something accessible from the external world, I had to pick `LoadBalancer`.

So this simple change fixed it:

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    targetPort: 8888
```

Now I finally have:

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
ci-master    LoadBalancer   10.15.243.32   35.211.12.22   80:32463/TCP   1m
```

Comment: This just got upvoted after 5 years, I just want to say I love Kubernetes

Answer (score 4):

With this configuration, you service is running on port 8888, and it is mapped to port 31388 of the node. So you can hit it on port 8888 from within the cluster, and on port 31388 from outside world.

About services, `targerPort` is the port the requests are sent to, so it is the `containerPort` of your deployment. These two ALWAYS need to match...

...And `port` is the service port. So your service is available on 10.103.13.96:8888.